# Understanding matplotlib magnitude_spectrum output

Tags: python, matplotlib, signal-processing

I'm having problems understanding the output generated by matplotlib's magnitude_spectrum function call.

I have generated a sine with 50khz frequency,

```
f_s = 488000.0 # Hz
t = np.arange(0.0, 1.0, 1/f_s)
s1 = 100*np.sin(2*np.pi*50000*t)
```

I then plot the resulting magnitude spectrum, after dividing by the number of FFT bins

```
s1_magspec = plt.magnitude_spectrum(s1,Fs=f_s)
plt.plot(s1_magspec[0]/len(s1_magspec[0]))
```

The result is a single spike at 50khz, but with a magnitude of 50, as opposed to the expected 100.

Can anybody explain why this is?

Here is a link to an ipython notebook describing showing the afforementioned code and the resulting plot:

http://nbviewer.ipython.org/gist/bkinman/22cc15d3ad3b9b2db09e

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like it has to do with the default setting for the FFT window used.  The documentation says that the default is a Hanning window.  If you use a boxcar window instead:

```
s1_magspec = plt.magnitude_spectrum(s1, Fs=f_s, window=np.ones(s1.shape))
```

you'll get your peak at 100, just like with a straight numpy FFT.

By the way, it would be good if you edited your question to put in the line of code creating `s1_magspec` rather than relying on the notebook viewer, the link to which will undoubtedly break someday.

Comment: Thanks! It seems that you were indeed correct! I have made the edit you requested.

Answer (score 0):

The amplitude (100%) is divided into negative (50%) and positive (50%) frequencies. You can see what I mean if you put in this code (note the `sides='twosided'`):

```
s1_magspec = plt.magnitude_spectrum(s1, Fs=f_s, sides='twosided')
```

[image]

Just be careful if you add some DC offset, e.g. 30, its amplitude goes completely to 0 Hz (note the `+ 30`):

```
s1 = 100*np.sin(2*np.pi*50000*t) + 30
s1_magspec = plt.magnitude_spectrum(s1, Fs=f_s, sides='twosided')
```

[image]